# How to get last update time of a file from linux kernel?

Tags: c, linux, file, linux-kernel

I am writing a linux module, which fetches data from a file. But this file may be updated by another processes. I wanted to know, How to get last update time of a file in C from linux kernel?.

Please also suggest me some techniques, by which I can easily judge whether a file has been updated or not.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding why this would be necessary. What is this file?

Comment: @duskwuff My module allows some specific user on the basis of entries in a file. It checks a file time to time, if file is updated it updates a buffer used by module....

Comment: Don't do that. Kernel modules shouldn't read configuration files. Store the configuration in the kernel, and allow it to be updated from userspace (e.g, using a `/proc` entry or a device node).

Answer (score 0):

Use vfs_stat to get get file status, this functions return information about a file like  time of last modification, time of last access etc.

vfs_stat symbol is exported, so you can call this function from kernel module.

```
#include <linux/uaccess.h>


mm_segment_t old_fs = get_fs();

set_fs(KERNEL_DS);
error = vfs_stat (FILE_PATH, &stat);
set_fs(old_fs);
```